# displaying an array data in a table using ng-repeat directive in Angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am building an application using Angular.js,Node.js and MongoDB.

I have got an array of data through ajax call and is as follows

```
[{
    "event":"treat",
    "expenselist":[
        {"text":"a","done":true,"value":"100"},
        {"text":"b","done":true,"value":"400"}
    ],
    "expense":500,
    "sharelist":[
        {"text":"b","done":true},
        {"text":"c"},
        {"text":"d","done":true},
        {"text":"a","done":true},
        {"text":"e","done":true}
    ],
    "shareno":4,
    "shareamount":125
},{
    "event":"lunch",
    "expenselist":[
        {"text":"c","done":true,"value":"500"}
    ],
    "expense":500,
    "sharelist":[
        {"text":"b","done":true},
        {"text":"c","done":true},
        {"text":"d","done":true},
        {"text":"a","done":true},
        {"text":"e","done":true}
    ],
    "shareno":5,
    "shareamount":100
}]
```

I am pushing the data one by one in an array `$scope.sharedetails` inorder to display each event in each row.

```
angular.forEach(data,function(event,k){
$scope.sharedetails.push(data[k]);
$scope.expensedetails.push($scope.sharedetails[k].expenselist);
$scope.attendeedetails.push($scope.sharedetails[k].sharelist);

  angular.forEach($scope.expensedetails,function(text,i){
     angular.forEach($scope.expensedetails[i],function(text,j){

if($scope.expensedetails[i][j].done==true){
$scope.spentpeople.push($scope.expensedetails[i][j].text);   
$scope.expensevalues.push($scope.expensedetails[i][j].value); 

}

});
});
  angular.forEach($scope.attendeedetails,function(text,i){
      angular.forEach($scope.attendeedetails[i],function(text,j){

if($scope.attendeedetails[i][j].done==true){
   $scope.sharelistresult.push($scope.attendeedetails[i][j].text);  
}

});
});
});
```

HTML:

```
              <td>{{sharedetail.event}}</td>
            <td><ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="spent in spentpeople">
            <span>{{spent}}</span>          
            </li>
            </ul>
            </td>
            <td>{{sharedetail.expenselist.value}}
            <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="expensevalue in expensevalues">
            <span>{{expensevalue}}</span>           
            </li>
            </ul></td>
            <td>{{sharedetail.expense}}</td>
            <td><ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="sharename in sharelistresult">
            <span>{{sharename}}</span>          
            </li>
            </ul></td>
            <td>{{sharedetail.shareamount}}</td>
            </tr>
```

I want the result like

```
Event |Spent By |Spent Amounts|Totalamount |Shared By |No of shares|ShareAmount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
treat |a        |100          |500         |b         |4            |125
      |b        |400          |            |d
      |         |             |            |a
      |         |             |            |e
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lunch |c        |500          |500         |b         |5            |100
                                           |c
                                           |d
                                           |a
                                           |e         |
```

I have edited my code.In this,I get the required result only when there is a single row.

When there are multiple entries(event),I get

```
 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=spent%20in%20spentpeople&p1=string%3A
```

How to display expense list array with "text" seperately and "value" seperately.
Please advice

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you want to get. Could you please provide an example of what shall be in result?

Comment: Please refer my edits

Comment: Why are you pushing your objects one by one ? (Understand it as, you shouldn't be doing it)

Comment: I have updated my latest code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to do all this pushing if you allready have a json array. Just asign it to the scope and render your table like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="sharedetail in sharedetails">
  <td>{{sharedetail.event}}</td>
  <td>
    <li ng-repeat="item in sharedetail.expenselist">
      {{item.text}}
    </li>
  </td>
  <td>
    <li ng-repeat="item in sharedetail.expenselist">
      {{item.value}}
    </li>
  </td>
  <td>{{sharedetail.expense}}</td>
  </td>
  <td>
    <li ng-repeat="item in sharedetail.sharelist">
      {{item.text}}
    </li>
  </td>
  <td>{{sharedetail.shareno}}</td>
  <td>{{sharedetail.shareamount}}</td>
</tr>
```

Look at this plunker here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8pvU4ZDxwt083p6QeIXz?p=preview)

Don't forget to setup the controller in the table tag.

Comment: But I have to check if "text":"b","done":true or "false".I want to display only the checked items

Comment: Just add an ng-if="item.done" to the list repeater. See here:http://plnkr.co/edit/RHLnIC4raTWuOAYsTjtO?p=preview

Comment: Can we also get the index of array sharedetails.

Comment: The <li> element should be a child or either a <ul> or <ol> for the html to be valid.